# Green pixelated issue when applying -vf flag to ffpmeg hls transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding, hls, transcode

I'm trying to create chunks of multiple bitrates to play them smoothly across various devices and bandwidth.
But the ffmpeg command output is creating green pixelated video. If I remove the **-vf** flag then the issue dissapears.

Resolutions are 720p,480p,360p.

FFMpeg cmd for **720p**:

```shell
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) \
       -vf "scale=720:-2,format=yuv420p" \
       -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -preset medium -profile:v main \
       -sc_threshold 0 \
       -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_segment_filename file_%03d.m4s \
       -y \
       file.m3u8
```

This is only happening in the case of **fmp4** and not with **.ts** file.[image: pixelated video]

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. What is the version of FFmpeg? How do you play the file? Is it reproducible when playing `file.m3u8` using VLC? It is reproducible when generating the following synthetic input video file: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=25:d=100 input.mp4`?

Comment: You are right @Rotem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was not creating the master playlist correctly due to which the video was pixelated with a green screen.
Check if you are doing **VBR** with multiple resolutions with different bitrates in **fmp4** then your output should have multiple **init.mp4**(init1.mp4,init2.mp4,etc) and correct master.m3u8 playlist properly linked to each fragment.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.